# How to get Google search headings with Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup, html-heading

I am trying to get the headings of Google search with Jsoup.
Here is my code:

```
    String request = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "&num=5";

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(request)
                .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                .timeout(5000).get();

        Elements headings = doc.select("h3");
        //headings array is empty

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get no results from doc.select("h3"). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Document's content, perhaps the request didn't go through properly or the result is different from your browser.

Comment: Hi, I have checked doc.toString() and I get some content. What is strange is that if i select, lets say "a", instead of "h3", I get the results normally.